# How to convert a DateComponents-object to a localized string, such as "08:40 PM", without specifying year, month, and day?

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdatecomponents

I have a "time" (hours and minutes) stored in a DateComponents-object, and I like to convert that to a localized string format such that 08:40 PM, och 20:40,  etc.

I now how to display a Date-object (NSDAte) in this way, but to convert 20:40 to a Date I must pretend I know the Year, Month, and Day.

**Question:** Is it possible to to convert a DateComponents-object to a localized string, such as "08:40 PM", by using TimeZone- and Locale-object, but without specifying the Year, Month, and Day?

Comment: I don't think you even need TimeZone, you can do all of the conversions with the Locale as long as you know the original format of the Date and the desired format.  Setting locale with automatically translate the date into a localized date string

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog, I agree that the TimeZone should be redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just get todays components and add the desired time to it. You will also need to specify a calendar:

```
extension Date {
    var year: Int { Calendar.current.component(.year, from: self) }
    var month: Int { Calendar.current.component(.month, from: self) }
    var day: Int { Calendar.current.component(.day, from: self) }
}
```

---

```
extension DateComponents {
    var todaysDateFromTimeComponents: Date? {
        let today =  Date()
        return DateComponents(calendar: .current,
                              year: today.year,
                              month: today.month,
                              day: today.day,
                              hour: hour,
                              minute: minute)
        .date
    }
}
```

---

```
let date = DateComponents(hour: 20, minute: 40).todaysDateFromTimeComponents // "Feb 1, 2017, 8:40 PM"
```

---

---

If you want to display “date information in a given time zone” you should use DateFormatter to format your date.

```
extension DateFormatter {
    convenience init(timeStyle: DateFormatter.Style) {
        self.init()
        self.timeStyle = timeStyle
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Date {
    static let shortTimeFormatter = DateFormatter(timeStyle: .short)
    func shortTime(with timeZone: TimeZone) -> String {
        Date.shortTimeFormatter.timeZone = timeZone
        return Date.shortTimeFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

---

```
date?.shortTime(with: TimeZone(identifier: "GMT")!)   // 10:40 PM +2hs
```

Comment: Yes, this might be the best answer, but you are in fact  specifying the year, month and date (to current). Maybe this information must be included(?)

Comment: @ragnarius I have added also a way for you to display the corresponding time of a date just passing the timezone that you would like to display

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get a localized date string is to use a `Date` with a `DateFormatter`. So the thing you have to do is create a date from date components. We can use the user's current calendar to do this. Once we have the date, just set the date formatter with the style you want to show; it should use the user's locale by default.

```
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.hour = 20
dateComponents.minute = 40

let date = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date!))  // 8:40 PM
```

Comment: be careful with this approach. the resulting date would be "0001-01-01 23:46:28 +0000" because of the year 0001. For instance the GMT returned  for my local would be GMT-03:06:28" when it should be GMT-03:00:00

Comment: Thanks +1 , I did not know that a Calendar object had a date method.

Comment: Yea, @Leo Dabus, do you have an alternative solution?

Comment: get todays era, year, month and day components or use 2001 instead of 0001

Comment: @ragnarius you can also access the dateComponents date property `let date = dateComponents.date`

Comment: @LeoDabus,  In my case, dateComponents.date becomes nil.

Comment: try setting the calendar property `dateComponents.calendar = Calendar.current`

Comment: If you set calendar it won't return nil

Comment: @ragnarius I have posted my answer also to your question

Comment: @LeoDabus, Okey, when I did set the calendar it did not become nil. Bt it is the wrong year and month. Could I trust the conversion when the month is incorrect, could there be a 1 hour daylight time involved?

Comment: Look at my answer would return the local date at the desired time. Then you can use DateFormatter to display it as needed

Comment: Don't forget to use the proper Calendar methods for your date calculations. Don't mess with the time zones. Just work always with local time unless you are creating a date string for your server API

Comment: @ragnarius BTW when doing date calculation that require to be time insensitive just use noon (12pm) for your calculation. Worth watching https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/227/